# How to find out specific key-value pair from a big json file using python

Tags: python, json

I have big json file where I am having multiple urls. The format is like this:

```
"url": "https://api/v1/test/fhfh"
```

I want to create csv file out of this which will include only the urls that will start with https://api

How can I do this in most efficient way?

Comment: Please, provide more details - e.g. what your input JSON looks like (obviously it's some nested structure) and expected output. Also show what have you tried so far and what particular problem you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in this way.

**json.json**

if you have big json with multiple url.

```
[
  {"url": "https://api/v1/test/fhfh1"},
  {"url": "https://api/v1/test/fhfh2"},
  {"url": "api/v1/test/fhfh"}
]
```

**code**

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('json.json', 'r') as f: # read json file
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    
case_list = [] # empty list
length_data = len(data)
n = 0
while n < length_data:
    if "https://api" in data[n]["url"]: # if https found then will append to case_list
        case_list.append(data[n])
    if n == length_data - 1:
        break
    n +=1

with open('case_list.json', 'w') as outfile: # write updated required json
     json.dump(case_list, outfile, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
df = pd.read_json ("case_list.json") 

df.to_csv ("case_list.csv", index = None) # change json to csv file.
```

**output**

```
print(df)
                         url
0  https://api/v1/test/fhfh1
1  https://api/v1/test/fhfh2
```